# can't run gmod server on raspberry pi 3 with exagear desktop

Tags: raspberry-pi3, garrys-mod

this is what i do at raspberry pi terminal

```
$ exagear
$ cd '/media/pi/NickTai HardDisk/gmodserver'       #its my harddrive
$ sh srcds_run -autoupdate -game garrysmod +map ttt_ANFANGSKARTE +maxplayers 6 +gamemode terrortown +ip 00.00.00.00 -port 27015
```

error:

```
Auto detecting CPU
Using default binary: ./srcds_linux
ERROR: Source engine binary './srcds_linux' not executable, exiting
Sun Apr  1 18:13:55 +08 2018: Server Failed
```

already

```
$ chmod +x ./srcds_run
$ chmod +x ./srcds_linux
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant.

The source dedicated server (scrds) is not compiled for ARM which is why the Pi fails to execute the binary.

Until Valve provides an ARM build of scrds, you cannot host from a pi which frankly wouldn't run very well anyway.